# Failed to start httpd server: Address already in use

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, httpd.conf

Surely I know that same question is already posted here. However, when I searched it, the status is different from mine and I cannot understand the answers. Therefore I post my problem here. Sorry for duplicating issues.

My homepage suddenly doesn't work and I found out that it failed to start httpd service. Following image is the result when I command 'sudo service httpd start'

> Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could
>   not bind to address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use: AH00072:
>   make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets
>   available, shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs
>                                                              [FAILED]

restart doesn't work also.

> $ sudo service httpd restart 
>   Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
>   Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind
>   to address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock:
>   could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available,
>   shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs
>                                                              [FAILED]

What should I do to restart httpd service and revive my homepage?

Comment: Seemed like a dupe, but couldn't quickly find another question with the same exact problem (most seem to be running the script directly from `/etc/init.d`). Therefore, answering instead of flagging.

Comment: see what PID is running on port 80 already and kill it. `sudo kill $(netstat -lntp | egrep ':80' | awk '{print $NF}' | cut -d '/' -f1 | sort -u) && sudo start httpd`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 98 usually occurs when some webserver is using the port, here 80, or
The clean release port/address was not done.

If port is being used by other webserver, shutdown the server. You can find out which service is using port 80 by

```
netstat -pan |grep 80
```

and then shutdown the service.

If the port was not released upon unclean shutdown of server, then

```
sudo service networking restart
```

to release address/port combination from bind. This usually fixes error 98 for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. So i looked to netstat:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

and received:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7836/docker-proxy
```

after killing process:

```
sudo kill 7836
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Files defined inside conf.d would have Listen port as 80 along with repetitive declaration of Listen port in httpd.conf which can cause this issue.
2. Seems port 80 is used by some other process, it can be checked by "netstat -anp|grep :80" Or assign a new available port to the Listen directive in httpd.conf and restart httpd.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/httpd/conf.d/ for unintended duplicate statements/files. We had somebody make a backup copy of a file there but they didn't change the extension, so it was still a *.conf file, included for processing.

Answer (score -1):

Your `httpd` server is already started. Try restarting the service instead of starting it again:

```
 sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: restart doesn't work....
$ sudo service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]